# Executing vacuuming on a postgres table

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

I had speed issues displaying a layer in Geoserver. The layer is retrieved through a postgres store. I have run auto-vacuum on the table (16million rows) and then things being faster. The issue is that I don't know why they are faster. Based on the outcome of the vacuum query:

```
INFO:  vacuuming "osm.asp_trs_roads_osm"
INFO:  "asp_trs_roads_osm": found 366524 removable, 9882216 nonremovable row versions in 425556 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet.
CPU 8.42s/13.92u sec elapsed 783.24 sec.
Query returned successfully with no result in 1285638 ms.
```

There were 0 dead rows. So if no change was applied why everything starts working fast after I execute the query?

Comment: **0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet.** - they all are removable. run the command again and compare the result

Comment: @ Vao Tsun it returns the same thing.

Comment: what command you run then?.. `vacuum (analyze verbose)`?..

Comment: This one: VACUUM FULL FREEZE VERBOSE schema.table_name

Comment: so the very first vacuum gace same result and dramatically speeded up queries?.

Comment: Yes. Does this make any sense? Shouldn't it be that in the second query the removable rows are 0?

Comment: well, if no transaction need older versions, yes, I'd expect them to be removed by `vacuum full`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150724/discussion-between-user1919-and-vao-tsun).